# Store the search queries of a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to store the search queries the users enter on my site. I created a model Searches with the corresponding database.

I don't want the user to know that I am creating an entry based on their search nor do I need to be able to access the searches from the site. I'll be reading the postgresql database directly every weeks. How can I implement this feature? I tried to do `Search.create!(@products)` when I am searching, but I get a `uninitialized constant PagesController::Search` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer the question with more code.
In your search method something like the following should do it and it should be undetectable since it is in the controller:

```
search = Search.new
search.user_id = current_user
search.term = @products.name
search.save
```

Comment: I forgot Search.new! Plus I had to create an empty model for search.

Comment: Well in your products controller, def search, make a new instance of the Search model. I made the assumption you already had a model for search.